# In Rails how do I use ajax? where do I put my Ajax code?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I get data from the database, without refreshing the page?

- I dont even know where to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails you will need to implement a page that pulls data from the DB and shows the data in whatever format you prefer, plaintext/json/xml. There's no asynchronous stuff in this part.

Ajax will be happening in frontend, the javascript part, that asynchronous connects to the webpage that you made above. jQuery's `$.ajax` will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make your AJAX call from either an onload.js or a page specific js file (example.js). You'll then need to run a `$.get` or `$.post` call to the URL of the data.

Here is a pretty detailed tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-ajax.htm